# separate mappings for TAB and C-i in .inputrc

Tags: bash, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, inputrc

For what I have tried, "TAB" and "C-i" in .inputrc seems to mean the same thing, whatever I bind to one is bound to the other. I know that originally, it was the same thing and that this behavior is kind of inherited from the old times but nowadays, apart from terminal emulators, all X applications makes the difference between a C-i and a TAB press.

So is there a way to run a terminal command ("complete" for example) when I press the TAB key and run another command when I press "C-i"?

(the same question applies for C-m and ENTER, C-z, C-d, and all these control sequences that I would like to send by other means than their original binding and apply my own commands to these precious keybindings)

And by the way, if you could explain a little bit the process from a keypress to a shell interpretation that would help me understand. For now I understood that keyboard events are translated by Xmodmap, then by .inputrc and that the result is interpreted by the shell or something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct connection between `xmodmap` and `.inputrc`.

There are a few ways, depending on the terminal emulator, for modifying the keys sent via the terminal.  Some of those include

- modifying the X keyboard configuration ([xkb](http://www.x.org/wiki/XKB/))
- modifying the keycodes sent for a given event ([xmodmap](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/X11/xmodmap.html))
- terminal-specific things such as the `translations` resource used by xterm.

However, in the normal situation, <kbd>control/I</kbd> sends a <kbd>tab</kbd> character because that is the way almost all terminals were setup.

With `xkb`, you can (in principle) change what the keyboard does.  In turn, the X applications detect key press and release events, and translate those into key symbols.  [`xev`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xev) is useful for showing events.  A terminal emulator running in X gets the series of events, which (using X library calls) it can translate into characters.  A `tab` is just another character in that case.

`xmodmap`'s role in that process would be as an ad hoc change to the X keyboard configuration.

If you happen to be using `xterm`, the `translations` resource gives a lot of configurability.  That is a feature of the [X Toolkit](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/upt/ch06_04.htm), which allows you to associate various key combinations with xterm's built-in actions.  The default key bindings are listed in the [manual](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#h3-Default-Key-Bindings).  You can override or add to those bindings.  There are several places where you can set the information (`$HOME/.Xdefaults` for example, though it can get cluttered easily). For example, I set the [`XAPPLRESDIR`](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/x-faq/part2/section-22.html) environment variable to point to my user directory which contains customized app-defaults files.  In one named `XTerm`, I could put this to change the result of <kbd>ctrl/I</kbd>:

```
*VT100*translations:    #override \n\ 
    Ctrl ~Shift<Key>I:string("??")
```

Because the <kbd>tab</kbd> key has its own special key-symbol, it is not affected by this translation.

Comment: The translation from X keysym TAB to C-i is done by the terminal emulator to send it to the shell. I need the TAB keysym to keep being send to all X applications when I press the Tab key of my keyboard. So I reckon that the only solution is to find a way to configure a terminal emulator to translate TAB keysym into a custom character sequence (other than C-i) so I can later assign them to what I want with .inputrc . Any idea how to do that? I've tried to find a way in xterm documentation but I cannot find anything about custom translations.